# Multiple variable derivations in pandas group-by object (time series)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a *DataFrame* according to spec. below. Actual size is around 100 million rows, and some 150 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3]
               ,'time_ref' : ['20150401','20150401','20150401','20150401','20150401','20150401','20150401','20150401']
               ,'time' : ['20150101', '20150201','20150301','20150401', '20150101',' 20150201','20150301','20150401']
               ,'disc' : [3,3,1,1,2,4,5,7]}
              ,columns =['id', 'time_ref','time', 'disc' ]
             ) 

for time in ['time_ref','time']:
    df[time] = pd.to_datetime(df[time]
                          ,format = '%Y%m%d'
                          ,errors = 'ignore')


df
```

I have solved the problem, which is to get the appearance below:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3]
               ,'time_ref' : ['20150401','20150401','20150401','20150401','20150401','20150401','20150401','20150401']
               ,'time' : ['20150101', '20150201','20150301','20150401', '20150101',' 20150201','20150301','20150401']
               ,'disc' : [3,3,1,1,2,4,5,7]
               ,'disc_agg_diff' : [-2,-2,-2,-2,2,2,2,2]
               ,'disc_agg_time_diff' : [2, 2,2 ,2,1,1,1,1]}
             ,columns =['id', 'time_ref','time', 'disc', 'disc_agg_diff','disc_agg_time_diff']
             )  

for time in ['time_ref','time']:
    df2[time] = pd.to_datetime(df2[time]
                          ,format = '%Y%m%d'
                          ,errors = 'ignore')


df2
```

- Column `disc_agg_diff` looks as difference between first change in variable `disc`, i.e. (1-3) = -2 at time point `20150301` for id` = 1. Then (7-2) = 5 at time point 20150401 for id 3.
- Column `disc_agg_time_diff` looks at how many time periods (months) back the change occurred. For id 1, 2 periods. For id 3, 1 period.

I am getting the result from a lot of groupbys, left joins and numpy.where working my way through each IDs and their monthly data points. The problem is that the code is now big, and if I add more variables with the same derivations is becomes bigger and a bit too messy.

**My questions is:** Can this result be obtained in a clean and efficient manner, code-vise, where the derivations done (subtractions) can be quotes, adding columns, etc. Also, speed is crucial since the data volume is really big.

Many thanks in advance for any time and considerations!

/Swepab

Comment: How come (7-2) = 2 . Its 5 right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo!

Comment: Logic is highly complicated. Can you add your solution to the problem based on groupby , left join and np.where? So we can come to a proper conclusion of logic and vectorize your solution.

Comment: Yes, the logic is somewhat complex, and to be frank I dont have the time to write it all down. Fully understand if you dont have time/possibility take it further!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform`. I found a rather good bog post explaining what it does on [pbpython.com](http://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html)

Something like this to get the first column

## `disc_agg_diff`

```
def get_disc_agg_diff(disc_column):
    return disc_column.diff().replace(0, None).dropna().iloc[0]
```

Depending on your data, using a for-loop might be more efficient that the `.replace`, `.dropna` and `iloc`

```
df.groupby('id')['disc'].transform(get_first_diff)
```

returns

> ```
> 0   -2
> 1   -2
> 2   -2
> 3   -2
> 4    2
> 5    2
> 6    2
> 7    2
> ```

## `disc_agg_time_diff`

works by approximately same as `get_first_diff

```
def get_disc_agg_time_diff(disc_column):
    diff = disc_column.diff().reset_index(drop=True)
    diff_reduced = diff.replace(0, None).dropna()
    return diff_reduced.index[0]
```

Here as well, the alternative is a for-loop, but this works.